# How to store PM2's configuration files under /etc/pm2 like Nginx's

Tags: pm2

I'd like to have PM2 configuration files structured under `/etc/pm2` like Nginx

```
/etc/pm2
/etc/pm2/pm2.conf
/etc/pm2/sites-enabled/*.json
/etc/pm2/sites-available/*.json
```

The reason for that is so all the configuration is structured in a consistent way, easy to manage PM2's user's permissions and easy to restart the processes (similar to `sudo service restart/reload nginx`). In addition I'd like the server automatically start all the processes when the machine is rebooted.

Is there an official/recommended way to accomplish something similar to that?

If not, how can I create a main `/etc/pm2/pm2.conf` that will include configuration files `/etc/pm2/sites-enabled/*`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ export PM2_HOME='/etc/pm2'
$ pm2 list
```

Comment: How does PM2 autoload configuration files from PM2_HOME path? Or what is the benefit of PM2_HOME? There seems to be no mention of it in the documentation.